# Run socket.io chat app in a website that's already running on wampserver

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have recently made this socket.io chat app with the help of online videos. But the problem is I modified the code and now I want to integrate it in a bigger website like a social network.

The problem, apparently, is the code can't find the socket.io.js file even though it is in it. I know you would usually run a server from gitbash, but it is already running one so why run gitbash as well?

The exact error is:

> GET http://localhost/socket.io/socket.io.js ERR: NET ABORTED

This is causing all the trouble.

Also, any opinions on doing all of this in php. I can do it in php, it's easy.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to load the file from

> http://localhost/socket.io/socket.io.js

HTTP requests directly to localhost will go to localhost port 80 by default, which you probably don't have a server running on.

Change the source of the js file to the port that your app is running on, should look like this:

> http://localhost:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js

Comment: i'm running my server using wampserver. so the port number should be 8000. although i do not write anything in the url when i access it